# CImg loading image fails with spaces in path name

Tags: c++, boost-filesystem, cimg

I have a C++ application that I am developing to scan an image and return coordinates, the whole application works as expected except for this last problem that I can't seem to figure out. a user uploads images to a folder, and then the images get run one at a time to the application in a queue. well the problem is, that we have thousands of users with many folders, and a good amount of these users upload folder/files with a space (ex: " "), in the folder/file name.

When the application runs it crashes, I have narrowed it down to the fact that CImg does not like spaces in the path.

Every time it runs on my local machine with a space in the path I get the following error, which doesn't seem to say much.

> Unhandled exception at 0x00BE05F7 in jpeg-info.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow >(parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00242000).
>
> [CImg] *** CImgIOException *** [instance(0,0,0,0,00000000,non-shared)] CImg::load(): Failed to open file 'J:\uploads\41039\test name'
>
> [CImg] *** CImgIOException *** cimg::fopen(): Failed to open file 'J:\uploads\41039\test name' with mode 'rb'.

the line of code it fails on is here.

```
const char* imagePath = filename.c_str();
CImg<unsigned char> loadImage(imagePath);
```

I just need to figure out a way to pass a path to CImg with spaces in the string and it not break.

Sidenote: I do have the boost filesystem installed if that makes it any easier to figure out this solution.

EDIT:

I was getting the filename two different ways with not luck on fixing this issue..

original way: (passing const char directly)

```
const char* filename = cimg_option("-i", "path/to/file/jpeg.jpg", "input jpeg path");
```

new way: (grabbing path and using boost to format it properly)

```
const char* getInput = cimg_option("-i", "path/to/file/jpeg.jpg", "input jpeg path");
std::string filename = boost::filesystem::absolute(getInput).string();
```

Comment: Can you show how you are getting the `filename`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I updated my question with what you are asking.